# Ipython 0.11+ : Accessing and manipulating configuration from interactive session

Tags: configuration, ipython

tIn the olde days of ipython (version 0.10 or lower) I used to be able to access and manipulate the running ipython instance from the interactive ipython session by using variable _ip available in the user's namespace, for example,

```
_ip.IP.rc.editor = '/usr/bin/jed'
```

I am beginning to use ipython 0.13 and apparently this "facility" is removed from user access. Is it still available and if so how to access it? I want to experiment with the prompt string, e.g. `c.PromptManager.in_template` in the new `ipython_config.py` file.

Comment: Aagh...I answered myself! For simple configuration variables, the `%config` magic does the job. For more fancy things, the `get_python()` function is accessible from user's namespace.

Comment: Correction: `get_ipython()`. I think Stackoverflow will let you answer your own question and accept the answer, so it doesn't show up as unanswered.